# Convert byte[] to UnsignedByte[]

Tags: java, arrays

I want to optimize the following java code (a single method):

```
private static UnsignedByte[] getUnsignedBytes(byte[] bytes){

    UnsignedByte[] usBytes = new UnsignedByte[bytes.length];        
    int f;
    for(int i = 0; i< bytes.length;i++){
        f = bytes[i]  & 0xFF;

        usBytes[i] = new UnsignedByte(f) ;
    }

    return usBytes;
}
```

This code basically converts a byte array(which is a file) to UnsignedByte array so that it can be send to a webservice that i am consuming through apache axis.

Is there any way i can avoid this for loop. Is there any direct method for this?

Thank you.

Comment: I would use Guava for such operations

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Are you aware that every UnsignedByte object takes at least 12 bytes (in a 64bit VM) for storing one `byte`? Hopefully you don't use this for storing large binary data...

Comment: @Robert: Yes, this is for 20M MAX file.

Comment: @pinturic: Can you share guava code? I couldnt find even that.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner: Its 7

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there is not. Conversion of the array of bytes has to be done by element.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with Guava this way:

```
UnsignedByte[] usBytes = Lists.transform(Arrays.asList(bytes), new Function<UnsignedByte, Short>() {
            @Override
            public UnsignedByte apply(@Nullable Byte input) {
                f = input  & 0xFF;
                return new UnsignedByte(f) ;
            }
        }).toArray(new UnsignedByte[bytes.length]);
```